# How to access to the parameter of the higher order function in scala

Tags: scala, higher-order-functions

I am really new to Scala and trying to study it.

I don't know how to access or using the parameter of higher order function. For example:

```
def higherOrderFunc(f: Int => Boolean): String = {
  /* Logic to print parameter is here */ 
  "Hello"
}

val func = higherOrderFunc(x => x > 1)
```

How can I print the value of x before I return value "Hello"

Comment: `x` doesn't have a value until you call `f`, for example if you call `f(5)` then x will be 5 and the return value will be 6 (which is not a Boolean, so I'm surprised if this compiles)

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I've already edit my stupid example

Comment: What you can do is: `higherOrderFunc(x => {println(x); x > 1})`. But then you also need to call `f` in `higherOrderFunc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. The argument does not exist in this context; it'd need to be passed into the higher-order function along with the anonymous function.